# How to run python in different directory?

Tags: python, linux

I am doing maintenance for a python code. Python is installed in `/usr/bin`, the code installed in `/aaa`, a python 2.5 installed under `/aaa/python2.5`. Each time I run Python, it use `/usr/bin` one. How to make it run `/aaa/python2.5`?

Also when I run `Python -v; import bbb; bbb.__file__;` it will automatically show it use `bbb` module under `/usr/ccc/`(don't know why), instead of use `bbb` module under `/aaa/python2.5/lib`

How to let it run python2.5 and use `/aaa/python2.5/lib' module? The reason I asking this is if we maintain a code, but other people is still using it, we need to install the code under a new directory and modify it, run it and debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the [shebang-line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) (if there is such a line)

Nomally

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

is used to start the python interpreter first found in the path, this is how virtualenv works, i.e. it changes the path so that the chosen interpreter is placed first and the line above simply works.

In your example, change i to

```
#!/aaa/python2.5
```

Note that the executable-flag has to be set for this to work.
Example:

```
$ chmod u+x script.py
$ ./script.py
```

See [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/2.7/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#envvar-PYTHONPATH) for a description of how python searches for modules.

Comment: Thanks for all answers. Under /aaa has code zzz.py, it has a line 'import bbb'. Currently when I run zzz.py, I think it automatically call bbb module under /usr/ccc/ (other people using, I can't modify it). How can I force it use bbb module under /aaa/python2.5/lib?

Comment: @truelies - see update, you need PYTHONPATH and/or PYTHONHOME variables set properly

Answer (score 1):

Do `/aaa/python2.5 python_code.py`. If you use Python 2.5 more often, consider changing the `$PATH` variable to make Python 2.5 the default.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.bash_profile` file (create if non exist, it's a hidden file):

```
python25(){
    /aaa/python2.5 "$1"
}
```

Now you can use Python (latest) and Python 2.5:

```
$ python my_file.py

$ python25 my_file.py
```

Good luck!